# how to trigger ajax update with radio button in Tapestry 4.0?

Tags: java, ajax, radio-button, tapestry

I've got two radio buttons (value A or B) and palette area below. I would like show palette when value A is selected and hide it when B is selected, so ajax update.
How to do it? 
I'm using old Tapestry 4.0.2 for existing project, so I can't upgrade.

Here is my code so far

Markup:

```
<span jwcid="models@RadioGroup" selected="ognl:modelOption">
   <tr>
       <td class="dataLabel" width="15%">
       </td> 

       <td>    
           <input type="radio" jwcid="@Radio" value="ognl:@com.example.MyPage@ALL"/> All models (Default)
       </td>        

   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td class="dataLabel" width="15%">
       </td> 

       <td> 
           <input type="radio" jwcid="@Radio" value="ognl:@com.example.MyPage@SPECIFIC"/> Specific models
       </td>

   </tr>       
</span>

<span jwcid="@If" condition="ognl:specificDeviceModels">
   <tr>
       <td class="dataLabel" width="15%">
          <span key="supportedDeviceModelsLabel">Supported device models:</span>:
       </td>

       <td>
           <div class="bundle_palette">
              <span jwcid="palette"/>
           </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</span>
```

Java:

```
public static final Integer ALL = new Integer(1);
public static final Integer SPECIFIC = new Integer(2);

public abstract Integer getModelOption();

public abstract List<DeviceModel> getSelectedDeviceModels();
public abstract void setSelectedDeviceModels(List<DeviceModel> deviceModels);

public abstract void setDeviceModels(List<DeviceModel> deviceModels);
public abstract List<DeviceModel> getDeviceModels();

@Component(type = "contrib:Palette", bindings = {"selected=selectedDeviceModels", "model=deviceModel"})
public abstract Palette getPalette();

 public IPropertySelectionModel getDeviceModel() {
    return new OptionValueSelectionModel(getDeviceModels()).sorted();
}

public void pageBeginRender(PageEvent event) {

    setDeviceModels(getDeviceService().findDeviceModels(null));
}

public boolean getSpecificDeviceModels() {
    //here I need to set boolean value and return it 
   return true/false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for this old version of Tapestry, I had to use tacos libraries:

http://tacos.sourceforge.net/components/tapestry/RadioGroup.html